# Upgraded to SqlServer 2014 but seems SqlServer 2012 is still running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was running SqlServer 2012 on a windows 8.1 system and ran the upgrade to SqlServer 2014. Everything said it completed successfully.  When I run Sql Enterprise Manager 2014, it shows V11 and not V12 when I connect to my "." running instance of SqlServer.

Is there a step I missed?

Comment: What does "upgraded to " mean? Did you install the two of them side by side perhaps? Did you explicitly select that you want to upgrade the default instance? In any case, what is the version number of the *server* you connect to? It's a four-part number. Are you sure you aren't looking at the version number of SSMS ? (There is no Enterprise Manager).

Comment: BTW SSMS is now a separate product that you can download for free

Comment: I thought I choose the "upgrade option" but don't remember exactly.  When I do help/about I get:Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.18350
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.9600  When I connect I see SqlServer 11.0.6020.0

Comment: Help/About shows the version of *SSMS* - the GUI tool. The database version appears next to the server icon when you connect to it. So what is the four part number that appears next to the server icon? Did you use a shortcut to the old version of SSMS perhaps?

Comment: (sorry, added after in above comment)

Comment: I uninstalled 2012 and reinstalled 2014 and it works the way I want now. Not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled 2012 and reinstalled 2014 and it works the way I want now. Not sure what went wrong. –